# How do I select query in a button that has been iterated using handlebars?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, handlebars.js

Hello and thanks in advance, I iterated buttons in handlebars, but when I try to refer to them using Id I get no response. I assumed its because its an ID and IDs are unique, so creating multiple would break the code somehow but I tried with classes and it didnt work either. This is the iteration from the handlebars file

```
<div class="timeline-wrapper">
      <ul class="timeline">
        {{#each moments as |moment| }}
        <li data-date="{{moment.date}}">
          <span class="title">{{moment.title}}</span>
          <div id="moment-dots" class="data show">
            <h3 class="description">{{moment.description}}</h3>
            <small class="date"> {{moment.date}}</small>
            <p class="^details">
              {{moment.details}}
            </p>

     <button id="get-history">What else happened on this day ?</button>

          </div>
        </li>
        {{/each}}
```

and here is the event listener I used as a click event to log "clicked" when clicked

```
function getValue (event) {

  if(event.target.id === "get-history"){
    console.log("clicked")

  }
}

var gethistory = document.querySelector("#get-history");
gethistory.addEventListener("click", getValue);
```

Tried using classes instead of IDs.

Comment: What do you mean by "I get no response"? How is this problem related to MySQL?

Comment: To select multiple elements, you use `querySelectorAll`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll. And, yes, as you mentioned, IDs should be unique. Using classes (or data-attributes) will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in [index](https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/data-variables.html#index) helper in handlebars to help you create unique ids or better yet, make use of `data-` attributes like so, note the `data-history="history-{{@index}}"` for each button:

```
<div class="timeline-wrapper">
   <ul class="timeline">
      {{#each moments as |moment| }}
         <li data-date="{{moment.date}}">
            <span class="title">{{moment.title}}</span>
            <div id="moment-dots" class="data show">
               <h3 class="description">{{moment.description}}</h3>
               <small class="date"> {{moment.date}}</small>
               <p class="^details">
                 {{moment.details}}
               </p>
               <button data-history="history-{{@index}}">What else happened on this day ?</button>
           </div>
        </li>
      {{/each}}
   </ul>
</div>
```

Then in your js:

```js
function getValue(event){
   console.log(event.target.dataset.history);
   // Do something with value
}

const historyButtons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-history]");
for(let button of historyButtons){
   button.addEventListener('click', getValue);
}
```

Note that the `{{@index}}` helper is zero indexed so your first button will translate to `data-history="history-0"`